# How to get div value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get div value using jquery in chrome console from this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="vou-col" style="cursor: pointer">
    <h4>Free Large Bucket</h4>
    <span class="sku-info">Voucher123</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

**$('.sku-info').val()**

VM783:1

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function
>       at :1:21

Comment: `$('.sku-info').text()` since a span object don't contain a value but only text

Comment: I also used: $('.vend-sku-info span').text()/$('.vend-sku-info span').val() but I am getting same error.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I used this but still getting error: VM1165:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:21

Comment: Have you included jquery?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes I have included jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problems

`.val()` is used to get the value of an **input** element - i.e. what the user has typed into a text box. It won't work for this purpose.

However, it should still be defined, even if called on an HTML element (it would still return `null`, though, so you would still have a problem). The only reason for `.val()` to be *not a function* would be if you had not included jQuery - insure that you have a line like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the `<head>` section of your webpage to include jQuery, otherwise none of the solutions below will work either.

### The Solution

You want to get the internal HTML value of a `<div>`. So, you should use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.val()`.

- `.text()` will return the text in the `<div>`, without any HTML tags;
- `.html()` will return all of the content of the `<div>`, including any HTML tags inside it.

### Example

```js
console.log($(".sku-info").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="vou-col" style="cursor: pointer">
        <h4>Free Large Bucket</h4>
        <span class="sku-info">Voucher123</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not enough information. Look at the error `$(...).val is not a function`. So, why isn't `val` a function? It **should** be a function even if you use it with `div` tag or `span` tag (although it should return null)

Comment: @clone The only reason I can see for this is OP not including jQuery - didn't notice this at first. I have updated my answer to include this information, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sku-info").attr('value')
```

should do the trick since this control is not an input

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text()/.html()` instead of `.val()` for this.. check updated snippet below.

```js
console.log($('.sku-info').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="vou-col" style="cursor: pointer">
    <h4>Free Large Bucket</h4>
    <span class="sku-info">Voucher123</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

It seems that your jQuery is running in no conflict mode - so `$` is the browser console's native function. This is often the case if using a version of jQuery which comes bundled with a CMS such as WordPress or Drupal.

**Solution**

You can use the full version:

```
jQuery(".sku-value").text();
```

We can infer this is the case because the error is ".val(...) is not a function" - if it were jQuery then .val *would* be a function.

**Useful debugging tip**

You can check to see if `$` is jQuery by seeing if it has a version number

```
console.log($.fn.jquery)
```

If $ is jQuery then this will log a version number - something like "2.1.1". If $ jQuery is not jQuery, it'll log undefined.

Answer (score 0):

include jquery

```js
var spanval = $('.sku-info').html();
alert(spanval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="vou-col" style="cursor: pointer">
       <h4>Free Large Bucket</h4>
        <span class="sku-info">Voucher123</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```